# Call a child class method in a parent two levels above?

Tags: java

So I have 3 classes.

public class A{}

public class B extends A{}

public class C extends B{}

I've instantiated an A object as new C object. I'm trying to call a method from C and it's not working. I've thought about making class A abstract but class B and Class C have different methods so if I did that I would have empty methods in B and C. Even if I made it abstract, the methods would have to be made in B instead of C since I think that's how abstract works.

So my question is how do I call a method from C if I instantiate it as an A object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if your A object is C:

```
A myobject = // get it ...

if (myobject instanceof C)
```

Then cast:

```
C really_C= (C) myobject;
```

and use C methods

Comment: Oh wow I completely forgot about casting. I think that will work! Thanks!